# Quiero imprimir los datos en un excel dinamico

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
  const students = [
        {
            name: 'John', edad: '25',
        },
        {
            name: 'Jane', edad: '23',
        },
        {
            hobbies: 'Cinema'
        }
    ]
const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(students);

const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
console.log(wb)
//ginerate boofer
const buffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
// binary data
XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'file.xlsx');
```

cuando le digo a la libreria XLSX que me exporta esa data me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que yo quiero que me salga es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y el código? ¿Dónde está?

Comment: perdon ahi esta..

Comment: En realidad la librería interpreta bien el JSON, porque en realidad es como si tu array tuviera 3 objetos (3 filas en Excel),y tú pretendes que interprete que son 4.Partimos de una conceptualización muy extraña de tu array, porque en tu resultado equiparas 'hobbies' con 'Jane' o 'Cinema',con lo que estarás de acuerdo en que al menos estructurado, no es.¿Qué pasaría si hibera otro estudiante (por ejemplo 'Julian' de 21 años) antes o después de lo de hobbies? ¿Saldría como las filas 2 y 3, o saldría de alguna otra forma? Si quieres algo tan personalizado, tendrás que rellenar las celdas tú mismo

Comment: Exactamente creeme que lo entiendo muy bien, pero es ni siquiera se por donde empezar para poder hacer eso. deberia obtener la ultima casilla de ese excel y decirle que apartir de esa casilla que ponga los datos, la verdad es que este es un ejemplo basico los datos se alimentan de la BD pero quiero que el excel sea dinamico y traiga los datos dependiendo. El ejemplo que tengo acá es lo que ocurre pero ni idea como puedo hacer eso alguna idea?

Comment: No trabajo con esa librería (yo utilizo otra generalmente), pero la clave estará en reformular tu array para que finalmente tenga como contenido 4 objetos, cuyos dos últimos serían `{name: 'hobbies'},{name:'Cinema'}`.

Comment: cual usas, y si quisiera hacer eso que dije como lo harias?

Comment: Yo utilizo [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs), pero la verdad es que SheetJS me parece genial también (por no decir mejor). Eso sí... tendrás que adaptar tu json o array de objetos al formato en que quieras que aparezcan los resultados. En cualquier caso, si lo haces en exceljs también tendrías que repasarlo 'a mano', de la forma en que comenté en el comentario anterior